# create html element that hovers around text area cursor using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I do not know jquery .
I am able to use javascript using examples from w3c.
So far I have allocated a separate space which I feel is neither convenient & wastage of precious web page space.
I am not able to find a way to get a text floating around the cursor in textbox . I want the floater to follow the keyboard cursor of text area . I have seen lot of examples in which mouse hover shows something .
Later I wish to alter the floater text dynamically as the cursor goes from one word to another.
I want to emulate something like http://google.com/transliterate/ . You see , they provide suggestion below the cursor.

Can you suggest ?

Thank you for listening.

Comment: We want to see some code

Comment: i added 'I want to emulate something like http://google.com/transliterate/ . You see , they provide suggestion below the cursor.'

ALso tell me where should I post my html web page code (>51K) ?

Comment: is title sufficient? <input type="text" title="something...">

Comment: that appeared when I moused over text box . I want something that appears alongside text box cursor.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea

Comment: to joe dyndale - my question is different in the sense that I want to create a floating text element around cursor in textarea .

Comment: i am not interested in getting caret position but am in need of floating text element around it . I am not able to figure out a way . Please give me a hint . This case is different from mouse hovering over any part of textarea.